# KendoUI: MVVM Autocomplete Events

Tags: events, mvvm, autocomplete, kendo-ui

I was searching all over but couldn't find an answer to my question. I'm initializing an autocomplete widget as the following:

This code is loaded into my DOM as a result of an Ajax request:

```
<div id="view_ticketCreate">
    <form id="jar_ticketing_create"action="" class="k-block jar-container">
        <fieldset class="login">
            <legend>Kontaktinformationen</legend>
            <p class="notice">Definieren Sie hier die Kontaktinformationen zu diesem Ticket.</p>
            <p>
                <label>Kunde</label>
                <input data-role="autocomplete" data-bind="source: customers, events{click: inject}" data-text-field="CName" placeholder="Suchen Sie nach dem Kunde" type="text" id="jtc_cID" class="k-textbox sourced">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Kontakt</label>
                <input type="text" name="jtc_cName" class="k-textbox">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>E-Mail</label>
                <input data-bind="value: cMail" type="text" name="jtc_cMail" class="k-textbox">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Telefon</label>
                <input data-bind="value: cPhone" type="text" name="jtc_cPhone" class="k-textbox">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Gerät</label>
                <select name="dID" class="k-textbox sourced">
                  <option value="000">Nicht geräte spezifisch</option>
                  <option value="001">CFBS01</option>
                  <option value="002">CFBS02</option>
                  <option value="003">CFBS03</option>
                  <option value="004">CFBS04</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Login</label>
                <input type="text" name="cLogin" class="k-textbox">
            </p>
        </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
<script>
      kendo.bind($("#view_ticketCreate"), view_ticketCreate);
</script>
```

in my main (an always loaded) JS file i got:

```
var view_ticketCreate = kendo.observable({
       customers: new kendo.data.DataSource({
           transport: {
               read: {
                   url: "http://server/API/customers/search/",
                   dataType: "jsonp",
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
               },
               parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                   return {
                       SearchTag: options.filter.filters[0].value
                   }
               }
           },
           schema: {
               data: "data"
           },
           serverFiltering: true,
           dataTextField: "CName",
            select: function(e){
                if (e.item == null) return;
                var DataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index())
                cPhone: DataItem.Telefon
            }
       }),
       inject: function(e){
           alert('ok')
       },
       cPhone: "0123456789",
       cMail: "asd@asd.de"
});
```

However,  the autocomplete search works perfect. But now I want to populate the fields jtc_cMail and  jtc_cPhone with values from my autocomplete request. But either the select: Function is working (not allowed here (guess because MVVM?), also the custom event inject is fireing.

I couldn't find anything how I need to go on. Please help me out.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Just have to use e.sender.dataItem function and pass in the index of the item selected.

```
selectPerson: function(e) {
var item = e.sender.dataItem(e.item.index());
viewModel.set("selectedPerson", item);
```

}

See jsbin http://jsbin.com/iLaK/3/edit